# Calculate new x and y coordinates after rotation

Tags: jquery, jcanvas

I'm rotating a jCanvas layer about its center, but after that I need to compute its new x and y coordinates. I'm using the below code, though it returns bad values:

```
var rotation = layer.rotate * Math.PI / 180;

//object's middle
var middleX = layer.x + layer.width / 2;
var middleY = layer.y + layer.height / 2;

//new coords (wrong)
var newX = middleX * Math.cos(rotation) - middleY * Math.sin(rotation);
var newY = middleX * Math.sin(rotation) + middleY * Math.cos(rotation);
```

For simple rotations - for example by 90 degrees I can get new  corner's x and y like that:

```
var middleX = layer.x + layer.width / 2;
var middleY = layer.y + layer.height / 2;
var newX = middleX - layer.height / 2;
var newY = middleY - layer.width / 2;
```

But what about more complicated cases?

EDIT:

I've found this formula, but it works properly only when I'm rotating clockwise. What about counterclockwise rotations?

```
var newX = (layer.x - middleX) * Math.cos(rotation) - (layer.y - middleY) * Math.sin(rotation) + middleX;
        var newY = (layer.x - middleX) * Math.sin(rotation) + (layer.y - middleY ) * Math.cos(rotation) + middleY;
```

Comment: What do you mean by its X and Y values? If you're rotating about the center, then the X/Y of its center won't change.

Comment: What's wrong with that? I mean the output

Comment: XY of what? The bounding box or the top-left corner? The middleX/Y will be the same as Chris said.

Comment: @ChrisHeald X and Y mean top left corner of the object. Since it's rotated 90 degrees to the right I want to calculate X and Y of the "new" top left corner which is former bottom left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are about to rotate about the center and get the new corner coordinate. Assuming you want to get the largest bounding box with the angle is not 90 degree:

```
var theta = layer.rotate*Math.PI/180.;

// Find the middle rotating point
var midX = layer.x + layer.width/2;
var midY = layer.y + layer.height/2;

// Find all the corners relative to the center
var cornersX = [layer.x-midX, layer.x-midX, layer.x+layer.width-midX, layer.x+layer.width-midX];
var cornersY = [layer.y-midY, layer.y+layer.height-midY, midY-layer.y, layer.y+layer.height-midY];

// Find new the minimum corner X and Y by taking the minimum of the bounding box
var newX = 1e10;
var newY = 1e10;
for (var i=0; i<4; i=i+1) {
    newX = min(newX, cornersX[i]*Math.cos(theta) - cornersY[i]*Math.sin(theta) + midX);
    newY = min(newY, cornersX[i]*Math.sin(theta) + cornersY[i]*Math.cos(theta) + midY);
}

// new width and height
newWidth = midX - newX;
newHeight = midY - newY;
```

Comment: Actually it still won't work - it gives me coordinates way too big, or way too small... And what do those cornersX, cornersY array mean? Why should I find corners relative to the center?

Comment: @nienawiedzony edited, now it gives correct value for the 90, 180, 270. But the other case really depends on what you want, I use the maximum rectangle that contains the rotated rectangle. since the rectangle is bounded by its four corners, you only need to know the extended of these four corners to define a new rectangle.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var theta = layer.rotate*Math.PI/180.;
    // Find the middle rotating point
    var midX = layer.x+ layer.width/2;
    var midY = layer.y+ layer.height/2;
    // Find all the corners relative to the center
    var cornersX = [layer.x-midX, layer.x-midX, layer.x+layer.width-midX, layer.x+layer.width-midX];
    var cornersY = [layer.y-midY, layer.y+layer.height-midY, midY-layer.y, midY-(layer.y+layer.height)];
    // Find new the minimum corner X and Y by taking the minimum of the bounding box
    var newX = 1e10;
    var newY = 1e10;
    for (var i=0; i<4; i=i+1) {
        newX = cornersX[i]*Math.cos(theta) - cornersY[i]*Math.sin(theta) + midX
        newY = cornersX[i]*Math.sin(theta) + cornersY[i]*Math.cos(theta) + midY
    }
```